# how to access the 'key and values' for a draggable using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const item = $(#draggable_item).draggable({
       snapTolerance: 10,
       containment: #drop_area 
 })

 console.log(item[snapTolerance])
```

I want the code to print out '10' but i dont know the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
const item = $(#draggable_item).draggable({
  snapTolerance: 10,
  containment: #drop_area 
 });

 console.log(item.draggable("option", "snapTolerance"));
```

This is the proper Getter for the Option.

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapTolerance

Comment: @Anon the `ui.draggable` is *jQuery object representing the draggable element.* This is used in Droppable and is not a reference to the Draggable itself. You can try `$(#draggable_item).draggable("option", "snapTolerance");` or `$("#" + ui.draggable.attr("id")).draggable("option", "snapTolerance");`

Comment: Thanks again. I deleted the question because I figured it out but this was the question for future use:  How to access it within a function. `ui.draggable("option","snapTolerance")` doesn't work